# SQL Query to satisfy 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I'm new to SQL and after designing the database, i'm having trouble with some queries. The query i'm currently struggling with states: 
"**A list of the customers who have ordered at least one project with a higher than average expected duration**."

```
    SELECT Customer.name
    FROM Project, Customer
    WHERE Project.c_id = Customer.c_id AND Project.exp_duration > AVG(Project.exp_duration)
```

I tried to implement this code but i keep gettin the following error message : "**An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.**"
Can someone help me with this? I've thought about using joins but i can't get it to work either.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the table variables (@Project & @Customer) with your real tables (Project & Customer).

```
DECLARE @Project TABLE
(
    p_id INT,
    exp_duration DECIMAL(18,2),
    c_id INT
)

DECLARE @Customer TABLE
(
    c_id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT @Project VALUES (1, 10, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 20, 1), (4, 10, 2), (5, 15, 2), (6, 20, 1)
INSERT @Customer VALUES (1, 'C1'), (2, 'C2')

-- average duration
-- SELECT AVG(exp_duration) FROM @Project

SELECT DISTINCT C.name
FROM @Customer C INNER JOIN @Project P ON C.c_id = P.c_id
WHERE p.exp_duration > (SELECT AVG(exp_duration) FROM @Project)
```

Comment: seems kind of complicated for someone who claims to be new at SQL

Comment: @james5 Do you have a simpler one?

Comment: It actually helped and worked for me! Let me just try to understand what you did. What i got from your resolution is that you created a subquery where you called the average from the project table only.

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives the list of Customers who have ordered at least one project (i.e. being a part of one or more projects) and whose *ExpectedDuration* is greater than the Average *ExpectedDuration*.

I have used left outer join, group by, count and avg aggregate functions.

```
Select 
    C.CustomerID,
    C.Name
From SampleCustomer C
Left Join SampleProject P
On C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
Where P.ExpectedDuration > (Select Avg(ExpectedDuration) From SampleProject Where CustomerID = C.CustomerID)
Group By C.CustomerID, C.Name
Having Count(P.ProjectID) >= 1
Order By C.CustomerID;
```